# Proving uniqueness in universal property of free products of groups

Tags: group-theory

The theorem: For any group $H$ and any collection of homomorphisms $\phi_\alpha: G_\alpha \rightarrow H$, there exists a unique homomorphism $\phi: *_\alpha G_\alpha \rightarrow H$ such that $\phi_\alpha = \phi \iota_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$ where $\iota_\alpha$ is the inclusion $G_\alpha \hookrightarrow *_\alpha G_\alpha$.

I think we are supposed to start by defining  the map $\phi (g_1 \cdots g_n)= \phi_{\alpha_1}(g_1)\cdots\phi_{\alpha_n}(g_n)$ where $g_i \in G_{\alpha_i}$. This seems to me to be the homomorphism we want. It is a homomorphism: take two reduced sequences in the free product $h, h'$, then $\phi(hh')=\phi(h)\phi(h')$ by definition. I suppose we could be worried about cancellation: say the last letter of $h$ and first of $h'$ cancel, that is: $h=kg_\beta$ and $h'=g_\beta'k'$ where $g_\beta,g_\beta'$ are in the same factor group. Then $hh'=kg_\beta''k'$ if they aren't inverses and $kk'$ if they are. In the former case $\phi(hh')=\phi(h)\phi(h')=\phi(kg_\beta)\phi(g_\beta'k')=\phi(k)\phi(g_\beta)\phi(g_\beta')\phi(k')=\phi(k)\phi(g_\beta g_\beta')\phi(k')=\phi(k)\phi(g_\beta'')\phi(k')$ etc. (This is correct, right?)

How do I show this is the unique map satisfying the inclusion property? I tried saying imagine there is some other homomorphism satisfying this property, but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Uniqueness is easy, the images of the $G_\alpha$ generate the coproduct (the term "free product" is very unfortunate).

Comment: Thanks Martin, but can you elaborate a bit more? I see that the images of the $G_\alpah$ under $\phi$ generate the coproduct, but why does this mean it is the unique map? I thought this would involve showing all other maps that satisfy this property must be $\phi$. I'm not really aware of other ways to prove something is unique.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I can't be sure, but I think it may be the term "free product" preceedes "coproduct" historically and, anyway, one belongs to group theory (and it is rather clear the meaning here) whereas the other one belongs to category theory. I still cannot free myself from this strong bias I have *against* category theory and I still see it, more or less, as a huge waste of energies and gray matter, all this said with all due respect for anyone dealing with it...

Comment: For $g \in G_\alpha$, $\phi(g) = \phi \iota_\alpha(g) = \phi_\alpha(g)$, giving uniqueness.

Comment: Say there exists another $\theta$ such that $\theta \iota_\alpha (g) = \phi_\alpha(g)$. We know that $\phi(g)=\phi \iota_\alpha(g)=\phi_\alpha(g)$. Thus $\theta \iota_\alpha(g) = \phi\iota_\alpha(g)$ for all $g \in G_\alpha$. This says that $\phi$ and $\theta$ agree on all single letters (singleton sequences) in the free product. Why is it enough to show that? It seems like that's what we are trying to prove.

Comment: If they agree on all single letters, then they agree on everything, because all elements in the group are products of single letters. It follows from the fact that $\phi$ and $\theta$ are both homomorphisms.